# Flutter Bloc Error : emit was called after an event handler completed normally - between two functions

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, bloc, dartz

I have the following problem...

> emit was called after an event handler completed normally. This is
> usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler. Please make
> sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers and use
> emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
> ensure the event handler has not completed.
>
> **BAD**   on((event, emit) {
> future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));   });
>
> **GOOD**   on((event, emit) async {
> await future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));   }); )

What happens is that in a function called **_onLogIn**, if the user has changed the language, it goes from there to another function inside the bloc, these two functions do not depend on each other, I mean that each function is called in different pages of the application, but still **_onLogIn** checks the **_onChangeLanguage** function.

```
  UserBloc({this.usecases}) : super(UserInitial()) {
    on<LogInEvent>(_onLogIn);
    on<ChangeLanguageEvent>(_onChangeLanguage);
  }
```

**_onLogIn function :**

```
void _onLogIn(
    LogInEvent event,
    Emitter<StateA> emit,
  ) async {

    emit(UserLoading());

    final userOrFailure = await services.logIn(
      x: event.x,
      y: event.y,
    );

    await userOrFailure.fold((user) async {

        /// If the user is logging in for the first time and does not
        /// have a preferred language.
        if (user.preferredLanguage == null) {
          emit(UserSuccess());

          emit(UserAlreadyLogged(connectedUser));

        } else {
          /// An ChangeLanguageEvent object
          ChangeLanguageEvent event = ChangeLanguageEvent(
            user.preferredLanguage,
            user.someId,
          );

          /// Call the other function in the same bloc
          this._onChangeLanguage(
            event,
            emit,
            isFromLogin: true,
          );
        }
      
    }, (failure) {
      emit(UserError(failure.message));
    });
  }
```

**_onChangeLanguage function :**

```
  void _onChangeLanguage(
    ChangeLanguageEvent event,
    Emitter<StateA> emit, {
    bool isFromLogin = false,
  }) async {

    final successOrFailure = await services.updateLanguage(
      event.language,
      event.someId,
    );

    await successOrFailure.fold( // ! HERE THE ERROR WHEN I LOG IN; but when i changed the language from the application i don't have an error
      (language) async {

        emit(ChangeAppLanguage(language));

        final sessionOrFailure = await services.getSession();

        sessionOrFailure.fold(
          (session) {
            /// I need this condition to know if the language comes from login
            if (isFromLogin) {
              emit(UserSuccess());
            }
            emit(UserAlreadyLogged(session));
          },
          (failure) => emit(UserError(failure.message)),
        );
      },
      (failure) {
        emit(UserError(failure.message));
      },
    );
  }
```

Any idea why? Thank you

Comment: i assume that `_onLogIn` is called inside some `on<...>` method, right? if so it seems that your `emit` is called *after* `on` method finished - most likely this is because your `fold` methods are not awaiting their `async` callbacks

Comment: @pskink Yeah yeah, both, i add it in the description

And have you an idea how can i fixed it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void _onChangeLanguage(
    ChangeLanguageEvent event,
    Emitter<StateA> emit, {
    bool isFromLogin = false,
  }) async
```

This should be a *major* red flag. A call marked as `async`, but not returning a `Future<>`. There is no way, the caller could possibly await this call. Or even *know* that they *should* await this call.

Make it return a proper `Future<void>` instead of just `void` and your bloc should pick up on that and properly await the call.

There even is a linter rule for this: [avoid_void_async](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/avoid_void_async.html). Did you turn off your linter? Don't do that. Turn your linter on and listen to it. Your other function has the same problem.

Comment: That helps me a lot, thanks! Put "await" before calling the other function too.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to return Future<...>, but have not done it in the 'switch' statement, rather I've used the 'break' on all cases. So a compiler have not pointed me the lack of the 'return' statement.
After I have put 'return' on all cases, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Also for other people landing here, if the code inside _handleDigit method is inside the event.event.map.

```
Future<void> _onKeyPress(
    Emitter<PincodePageState> emit, _KeyPressPincodePageEvent event) async {
  var digitToParse = '';

  event.event.map(
      digit: (digit) async {
        digitToParse = digit.value;
      },
      delete: (delete) async {},
      biometry: (biometry) {},
      empty: (empty) {});

  await _handleDigit(emit, digitToParse);
}

Future<void> _handleDigit(Emitter<PincodePageState> emit, String digit) async {
  // some async process
}
```